# How to import and use CGO Brotli implementation from google?

Tags: go, cgo, brotli

I am trying to import and use `cbrotli` implementation from [google](https://github.com/google/brotli/tree/master/go/cbrotli) as below:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    cbrotli "github.com/google/brotli/go/cbrotli"
)
```

But I am getting the below error while trying to run the program:

```
learn-go [master●●] % CGO_CFLAGS="-I /dev/projects/go/learn-go/src/brotli/c/include/brotli" go run cmd/compress/main.go
# github.com/google/brotli/go/cbrotli
src/github.com/google/brotli/go/cbrotli/reader.go:13:10: fatal error: 'brotli/decode.h' file not found
#include <brotli/decode.h>
```

I am not sure how to pass some C flags to make sure that I can use the brotli implementation

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you already have built `brotli`, if not, there is an installation instructions in their Github page:

```
$ mkdir out && cd out
$ ../configure-cmake
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

When building your Go app, you only need to pass `-I ~<prefix>/include`, where `<prefix>` is where you installed the header files for `brotli`. If you did not configure this prefix, it is usually in `/usr/local`.

After this, you can run using:

```
$ CGO_FLAGS='-I <prefix>/include' CGO_FLAGS='-L <prefix>/lib' LD_LIBRARY_PATH='<prefix>/lib' go run cmd/compress/main.go
```

**Note:** You don't need to add "brotli" at the end of your `CGO_FLAGS`

Answer (score 0):

A Go implementation is also available:

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/andybalholm/brotli"
   "net/http"
)

const in = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com" +
   "/google/brotli/master/tests/testdata/ukkonooa.compressed"

const out = "ukko nooa, ukko nooa oli kunnon mies, kun han meni saunaan, " +
   "pisti laukun naulaan, ukko nooa, ukko nooa oli kunnon mies."

func main() {
   g, e := http.Get(in)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer g.Body.Close()
   b := make([]byte, len(out))
   brotli.NewReader(g.Body).Read(b)
   println(string(b) == out)
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/andybalholm/brotli

Answer (score 0):

If installing on macos, you can use brew just fine (see [formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/brotli.json) for version).

```
brew install brotli 

# Copy the symlinks from brew prefix dir into /usr/local
sudo cp -r $(brew --prefix)/include/brotli /usr/local/include/.
sudo cp -r $(brew --prefix)/lib/libbrotli* /usr/local/lib/.  

# Compiler will check /usr/local by default.
CGO_ENABLED=1 go build ...
```